# Adding a new object,form creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an application that should be able to create a new object,my method must be able to accept data entered. I'm having a problem on adding code to assign a new guid value to my id property and initializing the service property for every new car class object.
My controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult Create(Guid?Id,Car model)
{
    If(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        bookingList=GetBookings();
        model.Id=bookingList.Count+1;
        bookingList.Add(model);
        TempData["bookingList"]= bookingList;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to assign a new guid to your `Model.Id` field. And as per your code it seems you're passing guid in request i.e. `Guid? Id`.

Assuming above, You can try the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult Create(Guid? Id, Car model)
{
    If(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       bookingList=GetBookings();
       model.Id= Id ?? Guid.NewGuid();
       bookingList.Add(model);
       TempData["bookingList"]= bookingList;

       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
    }
}
```

Here the line `model.Id= Id ?? Guid.NewGuid();` line will assign the Id which you've passed in request otherwise it'll assign new GUID.